PostgreSQL jsonb column with json fields and indexing
I'm experimenting with an application where users can create custom data fields using a set of predefined field types such as string, text, numeric, date, and array.
I'm planning to use the JSONB column type in PostgreSQL for flexibility and to avoid frequent database migrations.
The JSONB column will store field data organized by type (e.g., string, text) and individual field entries containing type information and values. I'm considering different indexing strategies for efficient querying based on field values and types.
Planning on utilizing the jsonb column type, hoping that it will be flexible and save some database migration time. I do not want to create new colums everytime a new field is created.
Simplified table creation script:
CREATE TABLE data_table(id int, fields JSONB, PRIMARY KEY (id));

'fields' column content:
{ 
    "string": {
        "test1": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "test test test"
        },
        "test2": {
            "type": "email",
            "value": "test123testtesttest123@test123testtesttest123.com"
        }
    },
    "text": {
        "test3": {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "test test test"
        }
    },
    "numeric": {
        "test4": {
            "type": "integer",
            "value": 123
        },
        "test5": {
            "type": "decimal",
            "value": 123
        }
    },
    "date": {
        "test6": {
            "type": "timestamp",
            "value": "2024-04-16T12:34:56Z"
        },
        "test7": {
            "type": "date",
            "value": "2024-04-16"
        }
    },
    "array": {
        "test8": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": ["test","2","test3"]
        },
        "test9": {
            "type": "integer",
            "value": [10,2,3.5]
        }       
    }
}

Planned indexes to be used:
used for string entries
CREATE INDEX data_table_fields_string_index ON data_table USING gin((fields -> 'string' -> 'value') gin_trgm_ops);

used for text entries
CREATE INDEX data_table_fields_text_index ON data_table USING gin((fields -> 'string' -> 'value') gin_trgm_ops);

used for numeric entries
CREATE INDEX data_table_fields_numeric_index ON data_table USING btree((fields -> 'numeric' ->> 'value'));

used date entries
CREATE INDEX data_table_fields_date_index ON data_table USING btree((fields -> 'date' ->> 'value'));

used for array entries
CREATE INDEX data_table_fields_array_index ON data_table USING gin((fields -> 'array' -> 'value') jsonb_path_ops);

PS strings/text and number/dates are using the same index type, adding them in separate ones because I'm planning
on doing some more processing, like removing html entries from one and i don't wan't to mix them up.
I've chosen to use GIN indexes with gin_trgm_ops for string and text fields to enable fuzzy text matching.
For numeric and date fields, I'm using B-tree indexes for efficient equality and range queries.
As a newcomer to JSONB and indexing, I'm unsure if my approach and index selections are on the right path.
Specifically, I'm curious about indexing the 'value' key versus the entire object, including the 'type' key?!.
Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

It's difficult to tell for sure without a benchmark, but looking at your data, I would say that you had better not use JSON, but a normalized data model. The flexibility that you desire will probably lead to bad performance with data modifications and joins. If you plan it well and avoid long transactions, and ALTER TABLE statement is no problem, and adding or dropping columns is fast.

@LaurenzAlbe thanks for the quick reply! This project goes along with java and entities/pojos. Would rather create 1 column as a 'bucket' rather than creating/removing columns everytime this needs to happen by a user. Comment noted btw!

You could consider a middle ground: Have the columns you know you always have, or that you want to filter or join by, be regular table columns and put only the mutating, volatile columns into a jsonb. Also, I recommend a flat JSON: nested structures, like grouping by data type, will certainly cause more pain than benefit.

@LaurenzAlbe regarding the flat json. Would i then only use one GIN index for all types, does that work?

Right. GIN indexes are expensive. You don't want more than one.
